# SVG showing not properly in Safari after copying SVG

Tags: svg

I am using dynamic generated SVG elements in our project. We change SVG pattern image dynamically, also duplicating SVG elements.

Everything is ok in all browsers except Safari. In Safari SVG element in not rendered properly after SVG element change.

My full code looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SVG background change</title>
    <script src="https://curtainsstyle.com/assets/template/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>#forCopy, #copied { width: 48%; float: left; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="drapes-svg">
    <div id="forCopy">
        <svg filter="url(#filtergAbCdEfGh)" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" width="400" height="1069.042316258352" viewBox="0 0 400 1069.042316258352" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <defs>              
                <pattern id="patterngAbCdEfGh" x="0" y="0" width="350" height="350" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="scale(0.4 0.7)">
                    <image width="350" height="350" xlink:href="fabric-default.jpg"></image>
                </pattern>              
                <filter id="filtergAbCdEfGh" x="-25%" y="0%" width="200%" height="200%">
                    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="7"></feGaussianBlur> 
                    <feOffset dx="2" dy="2"></feOffset>
                    <feComponentTransfer>
                        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"></feFuncA>
                    </feComponentTransfer>
                    <feMerge> 
                        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
                        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> 
                    </feMerge>
                </filter>               
            </defs>
            <g>
               <path fill="url(#patterngAbCdEfGh)" d="M36.972 0.891 C 36.971 1.136,36.243 1.336,35.353 1.336 C 34.236 1.336,33.459 1.647,32.843 2.339 C 32.238 3.018,31.887 3.162,31.751 2.784 C 31.642 2.478,30.967 2.227,30.252 2.227 C 29.538 2.227,28.953 2.027,28.953 1.782 C 28.953 1.537,28.552 1.336,28.062 1.336 C 27.572 1.336,27.171 1.537,27.171 1.782 C 27.171 2.027,26.614 2.227,25.934 2.227 C 25.207 2.227,24.431 2.595,24.053 3.118 C 23.480 3.914,22.900 4.009,18.610 4.009 C 15.706 4.009,13.808 4.185,13.808 4.454 C 13.808 4.699,13.224 4.900,12.509 4.900 C 11.795 4.900,11.093 5.150,10.950 5.457 C 10.742 5.902,10.638 5.902,10.431 5.457 C 10.288 5.150,9.787 4.900,9.317 4.900 C 8.847 4.900,8.463 4.699,8.463 4.454 C 8.463 4.209,7.661 4.009,6.682 4.009 C 5.702 4.009,4.900 4.209,4.900 4.454 C 4.900 4.699,4.585 4.900,4.200 4.900 C 2.303 4.900,2.227 5.486,2.227 20.235 C 2.227 29.314,2.385 34.298,2.673 34.298 C 2.948 34.298,3.118 36.674,3.118 40.535 C 3.118 44.395,3.288 46.771,3.563 46.771 C 3.808 46.771,4.009 47.171,4.009 47.661 C 4.009 48.151,3.808 48.552,3.563 48.552 C 3.285 48.552,3.118 51.225,3.118 55.679 C 3.118 60.134,2.951 62.806,2.673 62.806 C 2.378 62.806,2.227 81.960,2.227 119.376 C 2.227 156.793,2.076 175.947,1.782 175.947 C 1.486 175.947,1.336 203.997,1.336 259.206 C 1.336 309.868,1.175 342.523,0.924 342.613 C 0.671 342.704,0.468 482.457,0.399 702.716 L 0.286 1062.670 2.358 1064.743 C 3.498 1065.882,4.663 1066.815,4.947 1066.815 C 5.231 1066.815,5.854 1067.266,6.332 1067.817 C 7.377 1069.022,33.793 1069.444,34.187 1068.263 C 34.289 1067.957,34.666 1067.706,35.024 1067.706 C 36.075 1067.706,37.862 1065.616,37.862 1064.386 C 37.862 1063.762,38.062 1063.252,38.307 1063.252 C 38.552 1063.252,38.753 1062.937,38.753 1062.552 C 38.753 1061.651,39.825 1060.579,40.725 1060.579 C 41.110 1060.579,41.425 1060.379,41.425 1060.134 C 41.425 1059.889,41.826 1059.688,42.316 1059.688 C 42.806 1059.688,43.207 1059.488,43.207 1059.243 C 43.207 1058.998,43.608 1058.797,44.098 1058.797 C 44.588 1058.797,44.989 1058.998,44.989 1059.243 C 44.989 1059.488,45.503 1059.688,46.131 1059.688 C 46.916 1059.688,47.953 1060.385,49.443 1061.915 C 50.636 1063.140,51.882 1064.143,52.211 1064.143 C 52.541 1064.143,53.099 1064.543,53.452 1065.033 C 53.805 1065.523,54.451 1065.924,54.887 1065.924 C 55.323 1065.924,55.679 1066.125,55.679 1066.370 C 55.679 1066.615,56.281 1066.815,57.016 1066.815 C 57.751 1066.815,58.352 1067.016,58.352 1067.261 C 58.352 1067.506,58.753 1067.706,59.243 1067.706 C 59.733 1067.706,60.134 1067.906,60.134 1068.151 C 60.134 1068.434,63.549 1068.597,69.488 1068.597 C 75.427 1068.597,78.842 1068.434,78.842 1068.151 C 78.842 1067.906,79.443 1067.706,80.178 1067.706 C 80.913 1067.706,81.514 1067.506,81.514 1067.261 C 81.514 1067.016,81.871 1066.815,82.307 1066.815 C 82.743 1066.815,83.388 1066.414,83.742 1065.924 C 84.095 1065.434,84.654 1065.033,84.985 1065.033 C 85.801 1065.033,86.860 1063.919,86.860 1063.061 C 86.860 1062.676,87.060 1062.361,87.305 1062.361 C 87.550 1062.361,87.751 1061.804,87.751 1061.123 C 87.751 1060.396,88.118 1059.620,88.641 1059.243 C 89.131 1058.890,89.532 1058.330,89.532 1057.999 C 89.532 1057.183,90.646 1056.125,91.505 1056.125 C 91.890 1056.125,92.205 1055.924,92.205 1055.679 C 92.205 1055.434,92.606 1055.234,93.096 1055.234 C 93.586 1055.234,93.987 1055.434,93.987 1055.679 C 93.987 1055.924,94.494 1056.125,95.115 1056.125 C 96.313 1056.125,99.332 1058.754,99.332 1059.798 C 99.332 1060.119,99.733 1060.671,100.223 1061.024 C 100.713 1061.378,101.114 1061.937,101.114 1062.268 C 101.114 1063.084,102.228 1064.143,103.086 1064.143 C 103.471 1064.143,103.786 1064.343,103.786 1064.588 C 103.786 1064.833,104.187 1065.033,104.677 1065.033 C 105.167 1065.033,105.568 1065.234,105.568 1065.479 C 105.568 1065.724,105.969 1065.924,106.459 1065.924 C 106.949 1065.924,107.350 1066.125,107.350 1066.370 C 107.350 1066.615,107.951 1066.815,108.686 1066.815 C 109.421 1066.815,110.022 1067.016,110.022 1067.261 C 110.022 1067.506,110.807 1067.706,111.767 1067.706 C 112.767 1067.706,113.591 1067.944,113.697 1068.263 C 113.839 1068.690,116.713 1068.820,126.057 1068.820 C 135.401 1068.820,138.275 1068.690,138.418 1068.263 C 138.521 1067.957,138.988 1067.706,139.458 1067.706 C 139.928 1067.706,140.312 1067.506,140.312 1067.261 C 140.312 1067.016,140.713 1066.815,141.203 1066.815 C 141.693 1066.815,142.094 1066.615,142.094 1066.370 C 142.094 1066.125,142.401 1065.924,142.777 1065.924 C 143.663 1065.924,146.548 1063.040,146.548 1062.153 C 146.548 1061.777,146.748 1061.470,146.993 1061.470 C 147.238 1061.470,147.439 1061.069,147.439 1060.579 C 147.439 1060.089,147.639 1059.688,147.884 1059.688 C 148.129 1059.688,148.330 1059.373,148.330 1058.988 C 148.330 1055.020,152.517 1056.270,158.129 1061.915 C 160.808 1064.610,163.308 1066.815,163.683 1066.815 C 164.058 1066.815,164.365 1067.016,164.365 1067.261 C 164.365 1067.506,164.749 1067.706,165.219 1067.706 C 165.689 1067.706,166.156 1067.957,166.258 1068.263 C 166.401 1068.691,169.333 1068.820,178.910 1068.820 C 192.141 1068.820,192.873 1068.704,192.873 1066.624 C 192.873 1066.239,193.073 1065.924,193.318 1065.924 C 193.563 1065.924,193.764 1065.523,193.764 1065.033 C 193.764 1064.543,193.964 1064.143,194.209 1064.143 C 194.454 1064.143,194.655 1063.742,194.655 1063.252 C 194.655 1062.762,194.855 1062.361,195.100 1062.361 C 195.345 1062.361,195.546 1062.046,195.546 1061.661 C 195.546 1060.609,196.675 1059.688,197.964 1059.688 C 198.594 1059.688,199.109 1059.488,199.109 1059.243 C 199.109 1058.998,199.510 1058.797,200.000 1058.797 C 200.490 1058.797,200.891 1058.998,200.891 1059.243 C 200.891 1059.488,201.406 1059.688,202.036 1059.688 C 203.325 1059.688,204.454 1060.609,204.454 1061.661 C 204.454 1062.046,204.655 1062.361,204.900 1062.361 C 205.145 1062.361,205.345 1062.762,205.345 1063.252 C 205.345 1063.742,205.546 1064.143,205.791 1064.143 C 206.036 1064.143,206.236 1064.543,206.236 1065.033 C 206.236 1065.523,206.437 1065.924,206.682 1065.924 C 206.927 1065.924,207.127 1066.239,207.127 1066.624 C 207.127 1068.704,207.859 1068.820,221.090 1068.820 C 230.667 1068.820,233.599 1068.691,233.742 1068.263 C 233.844 1067.957,234.311 1067.706,234.781 1067.706 C 235.251 1067.706,235.635 1067.506,235.635 1067.261 C 235.635 1067.016,235.942 1066.815,236.317 1066.815 C 236.692 1066.815,239.192 1064.610,241.871 1061.915 C 247.483 1056.270,251.670 1055.020,251.670 1058.988 C 251.670 1059.373,251.871 1059.688,252.116 1059.688 C 252.361 1059.688,252.561 1060.089,252.561 1060.579 C 252.561 1061.069,252.762 1061.470,253.007 1061.470 C 253.252 1061.470,253.452 1061.777,253.452 1062.153 C 253.452 1063.040,256.337 1065.924,257.223 1065.924 C 257.599 1065.924,257.906 1066.125,257.906 1066.370 C 257.906 1066.615,258.307 1066.815,258.797 1066.815 C 259.287 1066.815,259.688 1067.016,259.688 1067.261 C 259.688 1067.506,260.072 1067.706,260.542 1067.706 C 261.012 1067.706,261.479 1067.957,261.582 1068.263 C 261.725 1068.690,264.599 1068.820,273.943 1068.820 C 283.287 1068.820,286.161 1068.690,286.303 1068.263 C 286.409 1067.944,287.233 1067.706,288.233 1067.706 C 289.193 1067.706,289.978 1067.506,289.978 1067.261 C 289.978 1067.016,290.579 1066.815,291.314 1066.815 C 292.049 1066.815,292.650 1066.615,292.650 1066.370 C 292.650 1066.125,293.051 1065.924,293.541 1065.924 C 294.031 1065.924,294.432 1065.724,294.432 1065.479 C 294.432 1065.234,294.833 1065.033,295.323 1065.033 C 295.813 1065.033,296.214 1064.833,296.214 1064.588 C 296.214 1064.343,296.529 1064.143,296.914 1064.143 C 297.772 1064.143,298.886 1063.084,298.886 1062.268 C 298.886 1061.937,299.287 1061.378,299.777 1061.024 C 300.267 1060.671,300.668 1060.119,300.668 1059.798 C 300.668 1058.754,303.687 1056.125,304.885 1056.125 C 305.506 1056.125,306.013 1055.924,306.013 1055.679 C 306.013 1055.434,306.414 1055.234,306.904 1055.234 C 307.394 1055.234,307.795 1055.434,307.795 1055.679 C 307.795 1055.924,308.110 1056.125,308.495 1056.125 C 309.354 1056.125,310.468 1057.183,310.468 1057.999 C 310.468 1058.330,310.869 1058.890,311.359 1059.243 C 311.882 1059.620,312.249 1060.396,312.249 1061.123 C 312.249 1061.804,312.450 1062.361,312.695 1062.361 C 312.940 1062.361,313.140 1062.676,313.140 1063.061 C 313.140 1063.919,314.199 1065.033,315.015 1065.033 C 315.346 1065.033,315.905 1065.434,316.258 1065.924 C 316.612 1066.414,317.257 1066.815,317.693 1066.815 C 318.129 1066.815,318.486 1067.016,318.486 1067.261 C 318.486 1067.506,319.087 1067.706,319.822 1067.706 C 320.557 1067.706,321.158 1067.906,321.158 1068.151 C 321.158 1068.434,324.573 1068.597,330.512 1068.597 C 336.451 1068.597,339.866 1068.434,339.866 1068.151 C 339.866 1067.906,340.267 1067.706,340.757 1067.706 C 341.247 1067.706,341.648 1067.506,341.648 1067.261 C 341.648 1067.016,342.249 1066.815,342.984 1066.815 C 343.719 1066.815,344.321 1066.615,344.321 1066.370 C 344.321 1066.125,344.677 1065.924,345.113 1065.924 C 345.549 1065.924,346.195 1065.523,346.548 1065.033 C 346.901 1064.543,347.459 1064.143,347.789 1064.143 C 348.118 1064.143,349.364 1063.140,350.557 1061.915 C 352.047 1060.385,353.084 1059.688,353.869 1059.688 C 354.497 1059.688,355.011 1059.488,355.011 1059.243 C 355.011 1058.998,355.412 1058.797,355.902 1058.797 C 356.392 1058.797,356.793 1058.998,356.793 1059.243 C 356.793 1059.488,357.194 1059.688,357.684 1059.688 C 358.174 1059.688,358.575 1059.889,358.575 1060.134 C 358.575 1060.379,358.890 1060.579,359.275 1060.579 C 360.175 1060.579,361.247 1061.651,361.247 1062.552 C 361.247 1062.937,361.448 1063.252,361.693 1063.252 C 361.938 1063.252,362.138 1063.762,362.138 1064.386 C 362.138 1065.616,363.925 1067.706,364.976 1067.706 C 365.334 1067.706,365.711 1067.957,365.813 1068.263 C 366.207 1069.444,392.623 1069.022,393.668 1067.817 C 394.146 1067.266,394.769 1066.815,395.053 1066.815 C 395.337 1066.815,396.502 1065.882,397.642 1064.743 L 399.714 1062.670 399.601 702.716 C 399.532 482.457,399.329 342.704,399.076 342.613 C 398.825 342.523,398.664 309.868,398.664 259.206 C 398.664 203.997,398.514 175.947,398.218 175.947 C 397.924 175.947,397.773 156.793,397.773 119.376 C 397.773 81.960,397.622 62.806,397.327 62.806 C 397.049 62.806,396.882 60.134,396.882 55.679 C 396.882 51.225,396.715 48.552,396.437 48.552 C 396.192 48.552,395.991 48.151,395.991 47.661 C 395.991 47.171,396.192 46.771,396.437 46.771 C 396.712 46.771,396.882 44.395,396.882 40.535 C 396.882 36.674,397.052 34.298,397.327 34.298 C 397.615 34.298,397.773 29.314,397.773 20.235 C 397.773 5.486,397.697 4.900,395.800 4.900 C 395.415 4.900,395.100 4.699,395.100 4.454 C 395.100 4.209,394.298 4.009,393.318 4.009 C 392.339 4.009,391.537 4.209,391.537 4.454 C 391.537 4.699,391.153 4.900,390.683 4.900 C 390.213 4.900,389.712 5.150,389.569 5.457 C 389.362 5.902,389.258 5.902,389.050 5.457 C 388.907 5.150,388.205 4.900,387.491 4.900 C 386.776 4.900,386.192 4.699,386.192 4.454 C 386.192 4.185,384.294 4.009,381.390 4.009 C 377.100 4.009,376.520 3.914,375.947 3.118 C 375.569 2.595,374.793 2.227,374.066 2.227 C 373.386 2.227,372.829 2.027,372.829 1.782 C 372.829 1.537,372.428 1.336,371.938 1.336 C 371.448 1.336,371.047 1.537,371.047 1.782 C 371.047 2.027,370.462 2.227,369.748 2.227 C 369.033 2.227,368.358 2.478,368.249 2.784 C 368.113 3.162,367.762 3.018,367.157 2.339 C 366.541 1.647,365.764 1.336,364.647 1.336 C 363.757 1.336,363.029 1.136,363.029 0.891 C 363.029 0.643,361.841 0.445,360.356 0.445 C 357.981 0.445,357.684 0.544,357.684 1.336 C 357.684 2.168,357.387 2.227,353.229 2.227 C 350.557 2.227,348.775 2.049,348.775 1.782 C 348.775 1.537,347.773 1.336,346.548 1.336 C 345.323 1.336,344.321 1.537,344.321 1.782 C 344.321 2.027,343.404 2.227,342.284 2.227 C 340.182 2.227,338.976 2.947,338.976 4.200 C 338.976 4.719,338.517 4.900,337.194 4.900 C 336.214 4.900,335.412 4.699,335.412 4.454 C 335.412 4.185,333.515 4.009,330.611 4.009 C 326.320 4.009,325.741 3.914,325.167 3.118 C 324.790 2.595,324.014 2.227,323.287 2.227 C 322.606 2.227,322.049 2.027,322.049 1.782 C 322.049 1.537,321.648 1.336,321.158 1.336 C 320.668 1.336,320.267 1.537,320.267 1.782 C 320.267 2.027,319.683 2.227,318.968 2.227 C 318.254 2.227,317.579 2.478,317.469 2.784 C 317.333 3.162,316.982 3.018,316.377 2.339 C 315.762 1.647,314.984 1.336,313.868 1.336 C 312.978 1.336,312.249 1.136,312.249 0.891 C 312.249 -0.021,307.154 0.371,306.459 1.336 C 305.911 2.096,305.306 2.227,302.352 2.227 C 300.338 2.227,298.886 2.414,298.886 2.673 C 298.886 2.918,298.686 3.118,298.441 3.118 C 298.196 3.118,297.996 2.717,297.996 2.227 C 297.996 1.455,297.699 1.336,295.768 1.336 C 294.543 1.336,293.541 1.537,293.541 1.782 C 293.541 2.029,292.353 2.227,290.869 2.227 C 288.736 2.227,288.196 2.369,288.196 2.927 C 288.196 3.312,287.910 3.913,287.560 4.263 C 286.836 4.987,284.633 5.130,284.633 4.454 C 284.633 4.185,282.735 4.009,279.831 4.009 C 275.541 4.009,274.961 3.914,274.388 3.118 C 274.010 2.595,273.234 2.227,272.507 2.227 C 271.827 2.227,271.269 2.027,271.269 1.782 C 271.269 1.537,270.668 1.336,269.933 1.336 C 269.198 1.336,268.597 1.537,268.597 1.782 C 268.597 2.027,268.213 2.227,267.743 2.227 C 267.274 2.227,266.799 2.478,266.690 2.784 C 266.554 3.162,266.203 3.018,265.598 2.339 C 264.982 1.647,264.205 1.336,263.088 1.336 C 262.198 1.336,261.470 1.136,261.470 0.891 C 261.470 0.636,260.134 0.445,258.352 0.445 C 255.531 0.445,255.234 0.530,255.234 1.336 C 255.234 2.152,254.937 2.227,251.707 2.227 C 249.290 2.227,248.118 2.402,247.981 2.784 C 247.846 3.162,247.495 3.018,246.890 2.339 C 245.954 1.287,241.871 0.834,241.871 1.782 C 241.871 2.027,240.955 2.227,239.835 2.227 C 237.522 2.227,236.526 2.955,236.526 4.645 C 236.526 5.275,236.325 5.791,236.080 5.791 C 235.835 5.791,235.635 5.590,235.635 5.345 C 235.635 5.100,235.033 4.900,234.298 4.900 C 233.563 4.900,232.962 4.699,232.962 4.454 C 232.962 4.185,231.065 4.009,228.161 4.009 C 223.870 4.009,223.291 3.914,222.717 3.118 C 222.364 2.628,221.718 2.227,221.283 2.227 C 220.847 2.227,220.490 2.027,220.490 1.782 C 220.490 1.537,219.889 1.336,219.154 1.336 C 218.419 1.336,217.817 1.537,217.817 1.782 C 217.817 2.027,217.416 2.227,216.927 2.227 C 216.437 2.227,216.036 2.428,216.036 2.673 C 216.036 3.460,214.472 3.147,213.808 2.227 C 213.361 1.607,212.655 1.336,211.483 1.336 C 210.557 1.336,209.800 1.136,209.800 0.891 C 209.800 0.643,208.612 0.445,207.127 0.445 C 204.751 0.445,204.454 0.544,204.454 1.336 C 204.454 2.029,204.157 2.227,203.118 2.227 C 202.383 2.227,201.782 2.027,201.782 1.782 C 201.782 1.537,200.980 1.336,200.000 1.336 C 199.020 1.336,198.218 1.537,198.218 1.782 C 198.218 2.027,197.617 2.227,196.882 2.227 C 195.843 2.227,195.546 2.029,195.546 1.336 C 195.546 0.544,195.249 0.445,192.873 0.445 C 191.388 0.445,190.200 0.643,190.200 0.891 C 190.200 1.136,189.443 1.336,188.517 1.336 C 187.345 1.336,186.639 1.607,186.192 2.227 C 185.528 3.147,183.964 3.460,183.964 2.673 C 183.964 2.428,183.563 2.227,183.073 2.227 C 182.584 2.227,182.183 2.027,182.183 1.782 C 182.183 1.537,181.581 1.336,180.846 1.336 C 180.111 1.336,179.510 1.537,179.510 1.782 C 179.510 2.027,179.153 2.227,178.717 2.227 C 178.282 2.227,177.636 2.628,177.283 3.118 C 176.709 3.914,176.130 4.009,171.839 4.009 C 168.935 4.009,167.038 4.185,167.038 4.454 C 167.038 4.699,166.437 4.900,165.702 4.900 C 164.967 4.900,164.365 5.100,164.365 5.345 C 164.365 5.590,164.165 5.791,163.920 5.791 C 163.675 5.791,163.474 5.275,163.474 4.645 C 163.474 2.955,162.478 2.227,160.165 2.227 C 159.045 2.227,158.129 2.027,158.129 1.782 C 158.129 0.834,154.046 1.287,153.110 2.339 C 152.505 3.018,152.154 3.162,152.019 2.784 C 151.882 2.402,150.710 2.227,148.293 2.227 C 145.063 2.227,144.766 2.152,144.766 1.336 C 144.766 0.530,144.469 0.445,141.648 0.445 C 139.866 0.445,138.530 0.636,138.530 0.891 C 138.530 1.136,137.802 1.336,136.912 1.336 C 135.795 1.336,135.018 1.647,134.402 2.339 C 133.797 3.018,133.446 3.162,133.310 2.784 C 133.201 2.478,132.726 2.227,132.257 2.227 C 131.787 2.227,131.403 2.027,131.403 1.782 C 131.403 1.537,130.802 1.336,130.067 1.336 C 129.332 1.336,128.731 1.537,128.731 1.782 C 128.731 2.027,128.173 2.227,127.493 2.227 C 126.766 2.227,125.990 2.595,125.612 3.118 C 125.039 3.914,124.459 4.009,120.169 4.009 C 117.265 4.009,115.367 4.185,115.367 4.454 C 115.367 5.130,113.164 4.987,112.440 4.263 C 112.090 3.913,111.804 3.312,111.804 2.927 C 111.804 2.369,111.264 2.227,109.131 2.227 C 107.647 2.227,106.459 2.029,106.459 1.782 C 106.459 1.537,105.457 1.336,104.232 1.336 C 102.301 1.336,102.004 1.455,102.004 2.227 C 102.004 2.717,101.804 3.118,101.559 3.118 C 101.314 3.118,101.114 2.918,101.114 2.673 C 101.114 2.414,99.662 2.227,97.648 2.227 C 94.694 2.227,94.089 2.096,93.541 1.336 C 92.846 0.371,87.751 -0.021,87.751 0.891 C 87.751 1.136,87.022 1.336,86.132 1.336 C 85.016 1.336,84.238 1.647,83.623 2.339 C 83.018 3.018,82.667 3.162,82.531 2.784 C 82.421 2.478,81.746 2.227,81.032 2.227 C 80.317 2.227,79.733 2.027,79.733 1.782 C 79.733 1.537,79.332 1.336,78.842 1.336 C 78.352 1.336,77.951 1.537,77.951 1.782 C 77.951 2.027,77.394 2.227,76.713 2.227 C 75.986 2.227,75.210 2.595,74.833 3.118 C 74.259 3.914,73.680 4.009,69.389 4.009 C 66.485 4.009,64.588 4.185,64.588 4.454 C 64.588 4.699,63.786 4.900,62.806 4.900 C 61.483 4.900,61.024 4.719,61.024 4.200 C 61.024 2.947,59.818 2.227,57.716 2.227 C 56.596 2.227,55.679 2.027,55.679 1.782 C 55.679 1.537,54.677 1.336,53.452 1.336 C 52.227 1.336,51.225 1.537,51.225 1.782 C 51.225 2.049,49.443 2.227,46.771 2.227 C 42.613 2.227,42.316 2.168,42.316 1.336 C 42.316 0.544,42.019 0.445,39.644 0.445 C 38.159 0.445,36.971 0.643,36.971 0.891 " stroke="none" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div id="copied"></div>

    <button style="position: fixed; z-index: 999999999; top: 0; left: 0" id="copy">Copy</button>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#copy').click(function() {
            var copiedSvg = $('#forCopy').clone().html();           
            copiedSvg = copiedSvg.replace(/AbCdEfGh/g, 'AbCdEfGh-replaced');
            copiedSvg = copiedSvg.replace('fabric-default.jpg', 'fabric-pattern.jpg');
            $('#copied').html(copiedSvg);
        });
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

What to do for Safari to render SVG properly after SVG element change (for example after changing svg defs pattern image href)?

Expected result shows in Chrome, Mozilla, but in Safari - not. Preview [here](http://needwebsite.eu/expected.jpg)

Where could be the problem? Why Safari shows not properly SVG after change?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to also show the code you use to change the SVG? And what do you mean by "rendering not properly"? What do you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: I have changed my problem description, added full code, preview images.

Comment: What happens if you set `overflow="visible"` for the `<svg>` element? In addition, you could try to apply the filter not to the `<svg>` element, but to the `<g>` enclosing the path. And if you inspect the cloned element in the developer tools, is the area shown for the SVG/its parent div identical to the one where you see its content? What is the computed height for original and clone?

Comment: Thank you very much ccprog - moving filter to <g> and adding overflow="visible" solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Moving filter to  elements solves the problem. Also, add overflow="visible" to make sure that filter is not cut.

Comment: what does "Moving filter to elements" mean?