# SVG not showing up properly in Safari/Firefox due to <filter> tag?

Tags: svg, safari, cross-browser, svg-filters

I have an SVG icon that is showing correctly in Chrome but not Safari/Firefox. I found this question in which the SVG in question looks similar attribute-wise: [SVG showing not properly in Safari after copying SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319706/svg-showing-not-properly-in-safari-after-copying-svg), however, the solution there does not work for me.

If I remove the entire `<filter>` tag, the SVG shows properly. I'm unsure if the filter is even really used since when I remove it the icon still looks the same. I exported it from a design tool called Figma so this was all auto generated.

Any ideas as to what could be preventing this icon's background from showing up in Safari/Firefox?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42" viewBox="0 0 42 42" fill="none">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_b)">
    <rect width="42" height="42" rx="8" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
  </g>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M21 11C20.45 11 20 11.45 20 12V27C20 27.55 20.45 28 21 28C21.55 28 22 27.55 22 27V12C22 11.45 21.55 11 21 11ZM28 19C27.45 19 27 19.45 27 20V27C27 27.55 27.45 28 28 28C28.55 28 29 27.55 29 27V20C29 19.45 28.55 19 28 19ZM13 16C13 15.45 13.45 15 14 15C14.55 15 15 15.45 15 16V27C15 27.55 14.55 28 14 28C13.45 28 13 27.55 13 27V16Z" fill="white"/>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter0_b" x="-24" y="-24" width="90" height="90" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="12"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="21" y1="0" x2="21" y2="42" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="#81B1FF"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#4185F4"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Firefox doesn't support the BackgroundImage pseudo input. Perhaps Safari doesn't either.

Comment: Ah, yea removing the <felGuassianBlur> causes it to show up correctly.

Comment: Well at the least, you should change the BackgroundImage to BackgroundImageFix - since that's clearly what's intended. But it looks like Figma is using a hack to grab the background image by specifying a feFlood with zero opacity. I'm guessing that's not going  to work correctly cross browser and could change any time.